# how to create a data email template using vba automatically in every sheet and email that certain data to individual person

Tags: excel, vba

```
    type sale price    UPC code    Profit
      A    25         15116841635   2
      B    20         131313313 3   6 
      C    15          151651651    4
      D    10         55615613      3
      E    29         22222222      4
      A    22        1123333        4.4
      C    25        351313131     4.8
      D    25        131313131     5.2
      C    23         31331333     5.6
      E     23       51511352       6
      A     30       132323232     6.4
      B     80      3233213213     6.8
      A     47      3131311313     7.6


        Date        

        Total Sales (total dollar value)    
        Total units     "(Total units, each line is one unit)"  
        Total profit        

        A   (total units in A)  (total profit from A) 
        B   (total units in B)  (total profit from b)
        C            --                --
        D            --                 
        E            --                 --


                         Product A      
               Upc code    sale price   profit

              list broken by each product in A catagory     

                         Product B      
               Upc code   sale price    profit

                    and other types (max 6 - 10 ) 



              each sheet will have no more than 200 products daily so 
              i am thinking i can use specific cells like A200 as a 
              specific reference to start, i am not gonna have more than 
              200 lines. i am looking for vba code to put data into  
             above format, then  look for email address in another sheet 
             using sheet name and then email above created format only 
             to that person via outlook,
```

i like to run a vba code that does following automatically in each sheet if possible,

I have a excel book with 40 sheets, each sheet is a sales of our individual store

column A is product type,  only 5 types

Column B is dollar value we sold it for

column C is product upc code

i want vba to create a email template that will have

- Total sales of that store
- chart that will show total units sold in each type
- chart that will show total dollar value sold in each type
- a list of upc code broken down into 5 types of product

Email that to a store, sheet name is store name and i have email address of each store in another sheet .. i will be getting reports daily

Comment: Plz add some code and workbook here, because your **"question"** is far to wide and not really easy to know if you hove already done something. I'm adding something that can be useful for you but [plz get aware of the forum rules](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: hello r3uk, i have created a sample sheet in my computer, how do i attach excel file to this forum .. thanks for fast reply, i am new to vba.

Comment: i get one sheet with all store data so far  i got code that separate each store sales and creates a new sheet with that store name

Answer (score 0):

Here are some pieces of code that might help you :

here to prepare a mail

```
Sub EnvoiMail(Subject As String, Destina As String, Optional CCdest As String, Optional CCIdest As String, Optional BoDyTxt As String, Optional NbPJ As Integer, Optional PjPaths As String)
  Dim MonOutlook As Object
  Dim MonMessage As Object
  Set MonOutlook = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
  Set MonMessage = MonOutlook.CreateItem(0)

  Dim PJ() As String
  PJ() = Split(PjPaths, ";")

  With MonMessage
      .Subject = Subject      ' "Je suis content"
      .To = Destina           ' "marcel@machin.com;julien@chose.com"
      .CC = CCdest            ' "chef@machin.com;directeur@chose.com"
      .BCC = CCIdest          ' "un.copain@supermail.com;une-amie@hotmail.com"
      .BoDy = BoDyTxt
        If PjPaths <> "" And NbPJ <> 0 Then
            For i = 0 To NbPJ - 1
                'MsgBox PJ(I)
              .Attachments.Add PJ(i)      '"C:\Mes Documents\Zoulie Image.gif"
            Next i
        End If
      .Display
  End With

  Set MonOutlook = Nothing
End Sub
```

Here to do charts :

```
Sub Graph()

Dim Gr As Chart

        Set Gr = ActiveWorkbook.Charts.Add
            With Gr
            'Définition des données sources du graphique
            .SetSourceData Source:=Range(Sheets(Src_Name).Cells(2, 1), Sheets(Src_Name).Cells(20, 5)), PlotBy:=xlRows
            'Type de graphique
            .ChartType = xlXYScatterSmooth
            'Place
            .Location Where:=xlLocationAsNewSheet, Name:=NewSheetName
            'Titre
            .HasTitle = True
            .ChartTitle.Characters.Text = "Chart Title"
            'Séries de données
            .SeriesCollection.NewSeries
            .SeriesCollection(1).Values = Range(Sheets(Src_Name).Cells(2, 2), Sheets(Src_Name).Cells(20, 5))
            .SeriesCollection(1).XValues = Range(Sheets(Src_Name).Cells(2, 1), Sheets(Src_Name).Cells(20, 1))
            .SeriesCollection(1).AxisGroup = 1
            .SeriesCollection(1).Name = "MTTF Calendaire"
            .SeriesCollection.NewSeries
            .SeriesCollection(2).Values = Range(Sheets(Src_Name).Cells(2, 2), Sheets(Src_Name).Cells(20, 5))
            .SeriesCollection(2).XValues = Range(Sheets(Src_Name).Cells(2, 1), Sheets(Src_Name).Cells(20, 1))
            .SeriesCollection(2).Name = "MTTR"
            .SeriesCollection(2).AxisGroup = 2
            .SeriesCollection(3).Delete
                        'épaisseur de la ligne tracée
                        .SeriesCollection(i).Format.Line.Weight = 1
                        'couleur des series
                        '.SeriesCollection(i).Format.Line.ForeColor.RGB = RGB(int1 as integer, int1 as integer, int3 as integer) ' pour une ligne
                        '.SeriesCollection(i).Format.Fill.ForeColor.RGB = RGB(int1 as integer, int1 as integer, int3 as integer) ' pour une area
            'Paramétrages des axes
            .Axes(xlCategory, xlPrimary).HasTitle = True
            .Axes(xlCategory, xlPrimary).AxisTitle.Characters.Text = "Age"
            .Axes(xlValue, xlPrimary).HasTitle = True
            .Axes(xlValue, xlPrimary).AxisTitle.Characters.Text = "Heures"
            .PlotArea.Interior.ColorIndex = 2
            .Axes(xlValue).MajorGridlines.Border.LineStyle = xlDot
            .ChartArea.Font.Size = 14
            .Deselect
            End With

            'Placement de légende
            With ActiveChart.Legend
                .Left = 350
                .Top = 75
            End With
            'Placement des la zone de tracage
            With ActiveChart.PlotArea
                .Width = 550
                .Height = 350
            End With



'faire le ménage
Set Gr = Nothing



End Sub
```